# Joomla news layout

Tags: layout, joomla, frontpage

How do I display the latest news on my front page and titles (with links) of other news below it in Joomla 1.5.?

I also need to set a fixed number of others news.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

1. "Module Latest News" with option "count: 1" positioned above:
2. "Module Articles Category" with option "count: [YOUR_NUMBER+1]"
3. and using CSS hide first element of "Module Articles Category"

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, if you are using standard Joomla articles, why wouldn't you use the standard Joomla Front Page Blog Layout menu item? This is pretty much what thatview is designed for and it wouldn't require any CSS to display the correct articles.

Comment: Hmm, I am using joomla 1.5.23 and when I go to Extension->Module Manager->New don't see Front Page Blog Layout. Maybe I need to install it? Or maybe I am not looking in right place?

Comment: It's a menu type. Add a new menu, select Articles > Front Page Blog Layout. Once you have created the menu, make it the default. Now you have an article layout on your home page that is simple to administer.